Swift: locationManager.authorisationStatus stays at .notDetermined - no user faced request is shown
I am trying to implement an app in SwiftUI and I need the devices location. I do not manage to get the user's authorisation - no request dialog is shown. The authorisationStatus always returns .notDetermined. What am I missing?
class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
            case .authorizedAlways: self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            case .notDetermined: self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            case .denied, .restricted: print("denied")
            break
            default: break
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        print(location)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location Manager failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}

I added the "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description" to the info.plist. Do I need to add more?

Yes, you have to add the entitlement. And inUse != always.
